# simulatenous/concurrent deployments under the same namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Are there any limitations in Kubernetes when it comes to deploying multiple deployments simultaneously or concurrently under the same namespace ?
This is assuming the resources are available and sufficient.

Comment: It seems that there is no limit on how many deployments can run under one namespace simultaneously as long as the resources can accommodate the deployments. You can check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/)

Comment: im asking more of the "deploying" activity itself. like can multiple users run kubectl deploy for various deployment objects under the same namespace